# Zen theme: understanding the zen grids design in _responsive.scss?

Tags: theming

Below is some of the code from _responsive.scss from the latest release of the Zen theme. It controls the layout of the page. Does anyone know what I have marked 'FROM HERE' to 'TO HERE' is for? I was following the Zen grids method fine until I came across this section of Sass. It doesn't appear in the five column layout, just the three column layout. Thanks

```
/**
* The layout when there are two sidebars.
*/
.two-sidebars {
  /* Span 2 columns, starting in 2nd column from left. */
  #content {
    @include zen-grid-item(2, 2);
  }

  /* Span 1 column, starting in 1st column from left. */
  .region-sidebar-first {
    @include zen-grid-item(1, 1);
  }

  /* Start a new row and span all 3 columns. */
  .region-sidebar-second {
    @include zen-grid-item(3, 1);

    --- FROM HERE ---

    @include zen-nested-container(); // Since we're making every block in this region be      a grid item.
    @include zen-clear();

    /* Apply the shared properties of grid items in a single, efficient ruleset. */
    .block {
      @include zen-grid-item-base();
    }
    /* Span 1 column, starting in the 1st column from left. */
    .block:nth-child(3n+1) {
      @include zen-grid-item(1, 1);
      @include zen-clear();
    }
    /* Span 1 column, starting in the 2nd column from left. */
    .block:nth-child(3n+2) {
      @include zen-grid-item(1, 2);
    }
    /* Span 1 column, starting in the 3rd column from left. */
    .block:nth-child(3n) {
      @include zen-grid-item(1, 3);
    }

    --- TO HERE ---

  }
```

}

Comment: The [SASS language reference](http://sass-lang.com/) has everything you need to know in it, from there it's just a matter of digging into the code for zen's mixins to find out exactly what, for example, `zen-grid-item()` does. At first glance I think it's applying a 3-column grid system to each block in the second sidebar region, each column spanning a width of 1 column of the containing grid

Comment: There is a lot of help re. the mixins at zengrids.com/help. But why is this code just included here? Why does it not appear at the same place in the five column layout? It looks unnecessary, but maybe there is a good reason for its inclusion. I'm looking for a Zen theme expert rather than Sass expert, I think.

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as 3cols being divisible into 12 (the overall number of cols) evenly, whereas 5cols isn't. It's just going to be something like that I would've thought. But I can open this up again its not a problem, thanks for clarifying

Comment: If you could, thanks. I think I understand the zen grids method, but I don't understand why the .block class needs to come to the party for this layout design?

Comment: At a complete guess, I'd say it's a design decision to allow the secondary region blocks to be a 3col responsive container themselves, maybe to intuitively support different ad dimensions or something like that. But is just a guess

Comment: AFAIK, `zen-grid-item-base` (in this instance) is pretty much just preparation for the `.block` elements to be styled with Zen Grids. As all blocks are given the `.block` class by default, it makes sense to standardise their properties across the board before adding any styling.

Answer (score 4):

*Note that this is also inside the `.region-sidebar-second` container

Also of note, is that zen-grids actually has nothing to do with Drupal apart from being created by [John Albin](https://drupal.org/user/32095). The documentation can be found [here](http://zengrids.com/help/).

**Quick and dirty explanation:**

```
--FROM HERE--

@include zen-nested-container(); // Since we're making every block in this region be      a grid item.
```

Ensures that the element (in this case, `.region-sidebar-second`) does not have any guttering (margins outside of the declared columns).

```
@include zen-clear();
```

This means that the sidebar region will have a clearfix applied

```
/* Apply the shared properties of grid items in a single, efficient ruleset. */
.block {
  @include zen-grid-item-base();
}
```

This applies a set of base styles to all blocks that will be in the sidebar. Things such as gutter width and box sizing. It takes something of an OOCSS approach in that it encourages DRY CSS (i.e. you don't need to apply the same CS to each block individually).

```
/* Span 1 column, starting in the 1st column from left. */
.block:nth-child(3n+1) {
  @include zen-grid-item(1, 1);
  @include zen-clear();
}
```

For 1st block in a group of three (`3n+1`), make the block 1 column wide, and place it in the first "column". Then assign a clearfix. I tend to read `@include zen-clear()` as *new line*.

```
/* Span 1 column, starting in the 2nd column from left. */
.block:nth-child(3n+2) {
  @include zen-grid-item(1, 2);
}
```

For 2nd block in a group of three (`3n+1`), make the block 1 column wide, and put it in the second "column"

```
/* Span 1 column, starting in the 3rd column from left. */
.block:nth-child(3n) {
  @include zen-grid-item(1, 3);
}
```

For every third block, make it 1 grid item wide, and put it in the 3rd "column"

```
--- TO HERE ---
```

**Useful links:**

*Note: As of August 13th 2013 these all work fine, but they might go over the next few years. If they do go and you notice, please be a darling and remove/update them from this answer ;-)*

- [CSS Tricks nth-child tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)
- [Zen grids documentation](http://zengrids.com/help/)
- [Nicole Sullivan's OOCSS code standards](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss-code-standards) (trust me, if you're using SASS then you're going to want to read this).
- [Harry Robert's fantastic CSS guidelines](https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines).
- The obligatory link to [CSSWizardy](http://csswizardry.com/) that I attach to almost every SASS/CSS question I answer.

Comment: Thanks. So why is it concerning itself with the blocks of .region-sidebar-second in the 3 column grid only? Why not in .region-sidebar-first too. And why not at all in the 5 grid column for larger screens. Why special attention to .block in .region-sidebar-second of the 3 column grid. What's special about that in particular? That's what I don't get.

Comment: Hmm..without scouring the Zen codebase, I couldn't safely answer.

Comment: My only guess is that the contributor is saying 'here's another feature that you could use with the sidebars', but there's no obvious explanation, to me at least. It doesn't look like it is required to me, but I've only just started to learn zen grids so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your question specific to .region-sidebar-second, and the special treatment it gets in the default 3 column layout (medium size screens): to fit into that screen size, the second sidebar gets moved to a new row in the grid, and then lines up the blocks horizontally, when there are two sidebars. That's the only thing special about it, that it gets moved down when there are two sidebars in that second screen size breakpoint.